# Logging into site with Post via JSoup

Tags: java, html, post, cookies, jsoup

I'm attempting to log into https://www.wheeloffortune.com/account via JSoup. Here is what I believe is only post-related html I need:

```
<form action="/account/Login" id="form-login-page" method="post">
<fieldset id="registration-login-modal-fieldset" class="standard-info">
<label for="email">Email<span class="notification">*</span></label>
<input autocomplete="off" data-required="true" data-val="true" data-val-regex="A valid email address is required." data-val-regex-pattern="^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._&#39;+&amp;])*[_0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-_0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$" data-val-required="Email is required" id="LoginEmail" maxlength="100" name="LoginEmail" type="text" value="" />

<label for="password">Password<span class="notification">*</span></label>
<input autocomplete="off" data-required="true" data-val="true" data-val-required="Password is required" id="LoginPassword" maxlength="20" name="LoginPassword" type="password" />
<a id="modal-forgot-password-link" href="/modal-pages/ForgotPasswordModal" class="js-modal">I forgot my password</a>

<div id="registration-modal-legal-checkbox">
<div class="form-error-modal-checkbox">
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The RememberMe field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
</div>
<label for="RememberMe" class="label-right preference-modal-options">Remember Me</label>
<input id="ReturnUrl" name="ReturnUrl" type="hidden" value="/" />
</div>
</fieldset>

<input id="submit-login-modal-form" type="image" src="/content/img/images/modal/register/btn-login.png" value="login" class="submit">
</form>
```

And here is my related Java code:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(this.site)
            .userAgent(this.userAgent)
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

Document document = Jsoup.connect(this.site)
            .userAgent(this.userAgent)
            .data("LoginEmail", <email>)
            .data("LoginPassword", <password>)
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .post();

System.out.println(document);
```

My document connection retrieves the site; but it still has me logged out. What am I doing wrong with my requests?

Answer (score 0):

Try also including the "Remember Me" and "Return Url" input, I've looked at the login request being made by the website and it seems like it is sending 4 input fields: **username**, **password**, **remember me** and **return url**. So try the following code:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(this.site)
        .userAgent(this.userAgent)
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

Document document = Jsoup.connect(this.site)
        .userAgent(this.userAgent)
        .data("LoginEmail", <email>)
        .data("LoginPassword", <password>)
        .data("RememberMe", "false")
        .data("ReturnUrl", "/")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .post();

System.out.println(document);
```

Comment: I gave that a shot, buy my status is still logged out. Any other ideas?